# Burbujas de Dialogo con keyframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Tengo el siguiente speech bubble o burbuja de dialogo que me dira si la figura en la que se encuentra el mouse es un cuadro o circulo,el punto es que la burbuja sale de golpe,como podria animarla para que salga mas despacio y suavizada

```js
    $("area").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('arriba').siblings().toggleClass('abajo')
    })

 function writeText(txt) {
     if(txt == "Esto es un circulo"){
        document.getElementById('bloque1').style.top = 0;  
        document.getElementById('bloque1').style.left =10;
        document.getElementById("bloque1").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("bloque1").innerHTML = txt;
        
     }
     else{
        document.getElementById('bloque1').style.top = 0;  
        document.getElementById('bloque1').style.left =250;
        document.getElementById("bloque1").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("bloque1").innerHTML = txt; 
     }
    
    
    }
function ondelete(){
    var div = document.getElementById('bloque1');
    if(div !== null){
        while (div.hasChildNodes()){
            div.removeChild(div.lastChild);
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#figuras {
    list-style: none;
  }
  .arriba {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  
  .abajo {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  .externo{
    position:relative;}
    div {
    transition: 2s linear 1s;
}

.interno {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 220px;
 background: #6495ED; /* el color de fondo */
 color: #FFF; /* el color del texto */
 font-family: Arial, Sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
 text-align: center;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 display: none;
}
.interno:after {
  border: solid 10px transparent;
  border-top-color: #6495ED;  /* igual al color de fondo */
  border-bottom: 0;
  bottom: -20px;  /* igual al borde + el padding-bottom de la definición anterior */
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 0;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<map name="mapa" class="figuras">
    <area id="p_area1" class="area1" shape="circle" coords="125,125,50" href="" 
    onmouseover="writeText('Esto es un circulo')" onmouseout="ondelete()">
    <area id="p_area2" class="area2" shape="rectangle" coords="325,75,425,175" href=""
    onmouseover="writeText('Esto es un rectangulo')" onmouseout="ondelete()">
    </map>
    <div id="bloque2" class="externo">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvHyu.png" usemap="#mapa" >
    <div id="bloque1" class="interno" >
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En vez de utilizar la propiedad `display` podes usar [opacity](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_opacity.asp), adicionalmente al desvanecerse de a poco la brubuja vas a notar que el contenido de la misma desaparece antes y queda medio feo, para lo cual podrias reescribir la funcion ondelete de la siguiente manera:

```
function ondelete(){
    var div = document.getElementById('bloque1');
    div.style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(div !== null){
        while (div.hasChildNodes()){
            div.removeChild(div.lastChild);   
        }
      }
    }, 500); 
}
```

Para un mejor entendimiento aca te dejo el ejemplo funcionando, con la funcion ondelete aplicada al circulo donde notaras este efecto "feo" que te describo y con la función ondelete2 en el cuadrado donde se logra un efecto mas logrado.

Saludos!

```js
$("area").hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('arriba').siblings().toggleClass('abajo')
})

function writeText(txt) {
   if(txt == "Esto es un circulo"){
      document.getElementById('bloque1').style.top = 0;  
      document.getElementById('bloque1').style.left =10;
      document.getElementById("bloque1").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("bloque1").innerHTML = txt;

   }
   else{
      document.getElementById('bloque1').style.top = 0;  
      document.getElementById('bloque1').style.left =250;
      document.getElementById("bloque1").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("bloque1").innerHTML = txt; 
   }
}

function ondelete(){
    var div = document.getElementById('bloque1');
    if(div !== null){
        while (div.hasChildNodes()){
            div.removeChild(div.lastChild);
            div.style.opacity = 0;
        }
    }
}
function ondelete2(){
    var div = document.getElementById('bloque1');
    div.style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(div !== null){
        while (div.hasChildNodes()){
            div.removeChild(div.lastChild);   
        }
      }
    }, 500);
}
```

```css
#figuras {
  list-style: none;
}
.arriba {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.abajo {
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
.externo{
  position:relative;
}

.interno {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 220px;
 background: #6495ED; /* el color de fondo */
 color: #FFF; /* el color del texto */
 font-family: Arial, Sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
 text-align: center;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
.interno:after {
  border: solid 10px transparent;
  border-top-color: #6495ED;  /* igual al color de fondo */
  border-bottom: 0;
  bottom: -20px;  /* igual al borde + el padding-bottom de la definición anterior */
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 0;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<map name="mapa" class="figuras">
    <area id="p_area1" class="area1" shape="circle" coords="125,125,50" href="" 
    onmouseover="writeText('Esto es un circulo')" onmouseout="ondelete()">
    <area id="p_area2" class="area2" shape="rectangle" coords="325,75,425,175" href=""
    onmouseover="writeText('Esto es un rectangulo')" onmouseout="ondelete2()">
    </map>
    <div id="bloque2" class="externo">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvHyu.png" usemap="#mapa" >
    <div id="bloque1" class="interno" >
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Oks,esta bueno y me gusta pero ese efecto se hace notorio cuando la burbuja se desvanece,pero quisiera a la hora de presentar el que nose presente tan bruscamente y repentina

Comment: El efecto es tanto para "aparecer" como para "desaparecer", o lo ves distinto? prueba cambiando la cantidad de segundos que dura la transicion en el estilo de la clase "interno" para que sea mas notorio.

Comment: Si ya lo vi y funciona hay como un pequeño desliz extra al pasar de un figura a otra por el retardo pero no queda mal,se ve bien,se veria mejor si pudiera hacer qe el div y el texto desaparescan a la par porque el texto se va primero,pero ya seguire viendo que mas puedo hacer con lo que me diste,gracias

Comment: Perfecto. para eso que el texto se va primero es la modificacion de la funcion ondelete que te propuse, si pasas el mouse por encima del cuadrado vas a notar que eso ya no sucede.